# Entity Join slow query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've never participated in a codereview before and I was pointed that I should in another thread for a slow query.

```
var longReturnListt =await (from i in db.Inventory_Vehicles
                        join l in db.Inventory_Descriptions on new {inv = i.ID, cli = i.ClientID} equals
                        new {inv = l.InventoryID, cli = l.ClientID} into descGroup
                        from m in descGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join s in db.Settings_Exports on i.ClientID equals s.ClientID into settingGroup
                        from sg in settingGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join sl in db.Settings_Lots on new {client = sg.ClientID, lot = sg.LotID} equals
                        new {client = sl.ClientID, lot = sl.ID} into lotsGroup
                        from lg in lotsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                  //      join se in db.Settings_ExportSites on new {client = lg.ClientID, lotId = i.LotID, site = siteId } equals new {client = se.ClientID, lotId = se.LotID, site = se.Site} into exportGroup
//from eg in exportGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join f in db.Inventory_Features on new {inv = i.ID, cli = i.ClientID} equals
                        new {inv = f.InventoryID, cli = f.ClientID} into invFeatGroup
                        from ifg in invFeatGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join p in db.Inventory_Photos on i.ID equals p.InventoryID into photo
                        from photos in photo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where
                        i.ClientID == "999995" && i.Archived != "1" && i.Holding != "1" &&
                        i.Status == "A"
                        orderby i.ID
                                           select new { i, m, sg, photoo = photo.ToList(), lg, ifg } into grouped
                                           group grouped by new { grouped.i.ID, grouped.i.ClientID } into groupedDone

                     //group photos by new {photos.InventoryID} into pg
                      select new NewType
   {
                          InventoryVehicles = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.i).FirstOrDefault(),
                          InventoryDescriptions = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.m).FirstOrDefault(),
                          SettingsExports = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.sg).FirstOrDefault(),
                      //    InventoryPhotos = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.photoo).FirstOrDefault(),
                          SettingsLots = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.lg).FirstOrDefault(),
                          InventoryFeatures = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.ifg).FirstOrDefault(),
                         // SettingsExportSites = (from pho in groupedDone select pho.eg).FirstOrDefault()
                      }).ToListAsync();
                     returnList.AddRange(longReturnListt);
                    return returnList;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Code Review! To get the best review we recommend you follow a few guidelines which are detailed [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, you will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better.

Comment: I don't know if he's sure yet, but I think the query just filters out active cars with client Id, I dont think you need any joins at all.

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh. Would a stored-procedure on the SQL side not work?

Comment: @ebrown I take it my solution is less than optimal?  I can experiment with a stored procedure.

Comment: First: use navigation properties, no `join`s. That probably doesn't fix anything but it makes the query far more comprehensive.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to see what actual queries this generates? Have you look at the execution plans of those queries? Are your tables properly indexed? What is the actual db set-up? Too many variables for us to determine what your performance issue is.